# What is this design element/field in Theme Creator?

Tags: themes, sony, sony-xperia

I'm working on a theme in Sony's Theme Creator and thus far, I'm pretty happy with my theme and its progress...

There is one problem however - I simply cannot work out what a particular element/field is named in Theme Creator and thus cannot change this element/field.

Either that or I have already made the change and it's not taking affect.

Further to this, I have experimented with changing anything that appears to be the right element/field (based on the name), however none have thus far had an affect.

The element/field is the blue parts below - they should be the same color as the bar at the bottom of the screen...

[image: Screen-shot of "About phone" screen]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Those elements you are referring to should be the "Status Bar" and the "Action Bar" (Top).  If you aren't sure which item in the left list corresponds to which element on the right, you can always press and hold the mouse button over the item in the list and it should show up as highlighted in yellow in the preview pane.